# Unable to load data in Webview or Webview is blank when clicking on listitem

Tags: java, android, webview

This is my webview actvity:

```
package com.example.murarilal.volley;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        webView.loadData(intent.getStringExtra("description"),"text/html","UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Mainactivity:

When I click on a listitem then in new activity webview appears blank. Nothing is there in the webview "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199" this is the URL. The same problem appears when I tested it on real device.

```
package com.example.murarilal.volley;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue queue;
    ListView listView;
    List<Hero> heroList;

    private String url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        home();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        heroList = new ArrayList<>();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArticleActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void home() {
        JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Hero hero = new Hero((String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("title"), (String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("urlToImage"));
                        heroList.add(hero);
                    }

                    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        queue.add(request);
    }
}
```

This is my mainactvity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.murarilal.volley.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching data from `intent.getStringExtra("description")` but you didn't add data into Intent which you want to pass, Try this,

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description","whatever data you want to pass");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

And load your URL in below way,

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: its just showing url in new activity when i click on listitem

Comment: You can pass whatever you want to show into the next screen. "url" was just an example.

Comment: @devesh And check updated answer which shows how to show load url so your webview can load site.

Answer (score 0):

Load an URL in webview:

```
private String url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199";
WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadurl(url);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String)